# Snowflake COPY with embedded double quotes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to copy a text file that has data that looks like this -

```
Samantha, Packer, "Patient saw Dr Smith for this "ache " on his wrist, insomnia" , "Aug 23, 1949"
```

When I use the COPY command, it throws an error - Found character 's' instead of field delimiter ','

I cannot change the input data. Is there any way I can load the whole string with or without the double quotes on the word **ache**?
I am currently using this -

```
TYPE= 'csv'
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
FIELD_DELIMITER = ","
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to fix an issue like this other than changing your data. Double-quotes that are part of the data itself need to be escaped like this `\"ache \"`. Your only option would be to remove `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'` but then you'll have issues with the commas that are supposed to be part of your data.

Comment: You could write a transformative SQL statement with a function like REGEXP_REPLACE to replace characters during copying if you can't change the file directly.  The double quotes can be escaped with another set of double quotes or you could use a different field delimiter like a pipe character instead of comma.

Comment: @Suzy Lockwood, If I replaced the double quotes with a pipe, wouldn't the problem still persist? I would need to specify pipe as my delimiter and it would still throw the same error.
Is there a way to replace just the inner quotes?

Comment: I meant you would replace your delimiter (comma) with a pipe so that it frees you up from the limitation of needing double quotes around the fields at all (assuming the main reason you want them is so they ignore the comma in the string). It gives options.  Yes, you can use the transformative SQL I mentioned to replace just the inner quotes.  I am not the best at REGEX, but I am sure there's a way to specify only the inner instance of double quotes in a field. You can test a few scenarios with small sample data.

Comment: You could also load the file in as a single long string into Snowflake and then parse it after the fact.  Not a very clean solution, but I'm not aware of any system that would successfully load that record as it is.  Typically, you'd want to escape your quotes and/or use a different delimiter.